# how to get full url with '#' in asp.net (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

How can I get the full URL with `#` in ASP.NET?

I want to get it with `#` part, this is the important part for me.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URL fragment (part after #) is not sent to the server, so you will need to use JavaScript to get it.

Comment: ooooh , thnx very much  , it's a very useful one :)